# How to accept anything but a certain word with regex

Tags: regex

So i have thins link http://www.test.com/en/something 
and now in the part where "something is" i should accept any word except "start", but i have no idea how to exclude just that one specific word

I tried http://www.test.com/en/* but that will just accept anything.

Comment: What is interpreting your regexp? sed/awk/grep/perl/javascript?

Comment: its implemented by javascript

Comment: Do you want to allow words like `started`, `starts`, `starting` etc?

Comment: All those are fine just need to exclude this specific case  http://www.test.com/en/start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
 http:\/\/www\.test\.com\/en\/(?:(?!start$).)+
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hG3hL2/7)

Comment: Explain downvotes please? so that i could improve the answer?